# Duvida onkeyup javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Quando digito no `input` alguma palavra, o texto digitado vai pra maiúscula.

No Mozilla Firefox e no Internet Explorer eu posso voltar o indicador que fica piscando pra digitar uma letra e posso editá-lo em qualquer parte.

Já no Google Chrome, toda vez que volto o indicador, ele vai automaticamente pro final do texto digitado. Como faço pra que fique igual aos outros navegadores, onde é possível voltar e não ir pro final do texto?

```
Nome: <input type="text" id="fnome" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sem Javascript

Experimente usar CSS para isto, ao invés de Javascript, dessa maneira não re-escreve o valor do input:

```
Nome: <input type="text" id="fnome" style="text-transform: uppercase;">
```

[Veja exemplo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/u9snku3s/1/).

## Com Javascript (jQuery)

Se fizer [questão do Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14508837/2387977) ou, por algum motivo, gostaria de manter o "efeito" de transformação das letras de minuscula para maiúscula e andar com o cursor pelo `input` sem que ele volte para a posição final, é possível fazer assim:

HTML:

```
Nome: <input type="text" id="fnome">
```

JS:

```
$("#fnome").keyup(function(){
    
    var start = this.selectionStart,
        end = this.selectionEnd;
    
    $(this).val( $(this).val().toUpperCase() );
    this.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
```

[Veja exemplo aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/mCNty/253/).

Comment: Desse modo funcionou, porem perde o efeito da letra indo pro maiúsculo.

Comment: Veja, adicionei exemplo com Javascript também.